# How to do a bitwise on a list of int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to make a bitwise operation in SQL to test several values in the same time
Instead of doing a loop on my int list. I wanted to know if there is a way to do like a in (contains)

```
select *
from TabA
where TabA.ID in (select id from @listOfIDs)
```

But instead of doing a in because it checks like a contains I want to check for every item in my list of int the bitwise operation

```
(ReferenceNumber & intItem) > 0
```

Severals informations to understand what i need.
I have a list of items and each items represent a value.(1,2,4,8,16, etc...) When i am saving checked items, it will be save as a number who is equal to the sum of checked items value.

I add a filter to filter this list with the same items and i want to do the reverse. Check if the item selected in the list ,inside my filter, is inside the number equal to the sum i selected before.

That's why i am using bitwise operator.

Someone has already work on this case?
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using `SQL Server` or `Oracle` ?

Comment: I have, for the moment, removed the conflicting dialect tags. Please only tag the dialect (and its respective RDBMS).

Comment: There may be support in some database systems for bitwise logic but, in general, in SQL you should be storing separate data items *as* separate data items, rather than encoding them into an integer.

Comment: @Squirrel sql server

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i try to reproduce .net bitwise implementation in sql that's why i am doing doing this way but i can change it of course.
I am using bitwise because it's an old code process and i can't change it for the moment

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `exists`.  It is a little unclear exactly what you are asking, but I think you want to check if any bit overlaps with the `TabA.id`:

```
select *
from TabA
where exists (select 1
              from @listOfIDs l
              where (TabA.ID & l.id) <> 0
             );
```

Comment: I add several informations, is it more clear?

Comment: @MatDev8 . . . Fix your data model.  Bit fiddling to store multiple items is generally not recommended in SQL.

Comment: usually in this db, we use intermediate table but for this one it was not created like this. The issue there is that if i create a new table, i will need bitwise compare for the migration because this db exist for severals years